# Rails: how can I share permanent cookies across multiple subdomains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

My app's register and login processes take place on a secure subdomain. For this reason, I have modified `config/initializers/session_store.rb` to look like

```
if Rails.env.production?
  AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_app_name_session', :domain => '.app_name.com'
else
  AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_app_name_session'
end
```

so that the session can be shared across sub domains.

How can I share permanent cookies accross subdomains so that when I set a permanent cookie
on one subdomain via `cookies.permanent[:some_key] = 'some value'`, I can access that cookie on another subdomain via `cookies[:some_key]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the domain using a more verbose cookie setting method:

```
cookies[:some_cookie] = {
  :value => "whatever",
  :domain => ".app_name.com",
  :expires => 1.year.from_now.utc
}
```

I haven't found a configuration setting to do this globally yet.