# How to single sign on services work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, single-sign-on

If I have 10 websites, how can I create a single-sign-on such that if they login to any of the 10 websites, going to the other websites automatically detects they are logged in and logs them in.

How is this done?  You can't share cookies between domains, so how can you detect if the user logged into any of the 10 sites?

Comment: here's a SO question on cross-domain cookie sharing: http://stackoverflow.com/q/263010/366493

Answer (score 0):

Use more verbose cookie setting method

[Rails: how can I share permanent cookies across multiple subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301121/rails-how-can-i-share-permanent-cookies-across-multiple-subdomains)

Comment: I don't believe the question limited the application to subdomains.

Answer (score -2):

See the List of single sign-on implementations here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations

Comment: That describes concepts but doesn't help with implementation.

Comment: The technical implementation will depend on SSO technology chosen. The original question is not specific enough to provide technical details.